# Google Maps API V3 not showing map

Tags: php, html, ajax, google-maps-api-3, kml

Okay so I have a PHP script which handles file uploads, KML files specifically, extracts the center point and the location of the uploaded file, saves these details in text files, and then loads another page via "header". This other page then uses AJAX calls to set variable names as gathered from the text files, for the location of the KML file and the center point, in order to call the Google Maps API to show the KML layer upon a map.

That is what is supposed to happen, but instead nothing appears. I browse for my KML file, hit the upload button, and a blank page is shown. When I check my server, the file as been uploaded and the relevant details written into their respective text files, so obviously something is going wrong when I try to call the Google Maps API.

PHP upload and file info saving:

```
<?php
//Check that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["UploadedFile"])) && ($_FILES['UploadedFile']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 3Mb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['UploadedFile']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "kml") && ($_FILES["UploadedFile"]["size"] < 3145728)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/kml/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadedFile']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           findCenter($newname);
           saveName($newname);
        } else {
           echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["UploadedFile"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .kml files under 3Mb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}

function findCenter($file) {
   $kmlContent = file_get_contents($file);

   $startName = "#sh_green-circle";
   $endName = "#sh_red-circle";
   $startCoords = getCoords($kmlContent, $startName);
   $endCoords = getCoords($kmlContent, $endName);

   $startLat = substr($startCoords, strrpos($startCoords, ',') +1);
   $startLong = substr($startCoords, 0, strrpos($startCoords, ','));

   $endLat = substr($endCoords, strrpos($endCoords, ',') +1);
   $endLong = substr($endCoords, 0, strrpos($endCoords, ','));

   $midLat = ($startLat+$endLat)/2;
   $midLong = ($startLong+$endLong)/2;

   $midCoord = "$midLat,$midLong";

   $saveCenter = "kmlcenter.txt";
   $fh = fopen($saveCenter, 'w') or die ("Can't create file");
   $stringData = $midCoord;
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   fclose($fh);
}

function getCoords($kml, $name) {
   $startSearch = strpos($kml, $name);
   $midSearch = strpos($kml, "<coordinates>", $startSearch+1);
   $endSearch = strpos($kml, "</coordinates>", $midSearch+1);

   $longlat = substr($kml, $midSearch+13, $endSearch-($midSearch+13));
   return $longlat;
}

function saveName($filename) {
   $saveFile = "kmlfilename.txt";
   $fh = fopen($saveFile, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
   $stringData = "$filename";
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   fclose($fh);
   header("Location: initgmaps.html");
}
?>
```

Map intitialisation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8P7CzxiwQFf-RdK9QVRpH9se8AsMSsjEsensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var kmlName = getName()
  var kmlCoords = getCoords()
  var mapcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(kmlCoords);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: mapcenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("infoArea"), myOptions);

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlName);
  kmlLayer.setMap(map);
}
</script>
```

Relevant AJAX functions:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function getName(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    var kmlName;
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
       // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
       ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
               kmlName = ajaxRequest.responseText;   
               }
       }
       ajaxRequest.open("GET", "kmlfilename.txt", false);
       ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
//-->

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function getCoords(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    var kmlCoords;
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
       // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
       ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
               kmlCoords = ajaxRequest.responseText;   
               }
       }
       ajaxRequest.open("GET", "kmlcenter.txt", false);
       ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
//-->
```

And of course in the body of initgmaps.html I have:

```
onload="initialize()"
```

infoArea is the ID for my inline frame.

Can anyone see why it doesn't load? I'm completely and utterly new to web development, learning as I go, so sorry if the code is terrible and I'm sure I've made some obvious errors. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8P7CzxiwQFf-RdK9QVRpH9se8AsMSsjEsensor=false"></script>
```

You have missed an ampersand here... Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[[YOUR-GMAPS-KEY]]&sensor=false"></script>
```

(Where **[[YOUR-GMAPS-KEY]]** is your Google Maps Key - "*AIzaSyB8P7CzxiwQFf-RdK9QV...*".)

Comment: Oh jeez what a stupid mistake, at least that bit was a quick fix. Still doesn't show anything though :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an ampersand '&' after your key and before the sensor=false parameter.

### Additionally

var kmlCoords = getCoords()

is javascript, but function getCoords() is PHP. Javascript cannot execute a PHP function.

Comment: getCoords is also a javascript function in my AJAX request. Seeing as PHP and javascript can't see each other, does this matter? I've changed getCoords() in my PHP to findCoords() and still nothing shows.

Comment: I see... But the javascript function getCoords() doesn't return anything. Try adding return kmlCoords.

Comment: If you care to post a link to a live page then we could run it through a proper debugger. My browser is a lot better than my eyeball at doing that. :-)

Comment: I have Firebug and it's telling me "google is undefined". Rage.

Comment: http://paul.badtoro.co.uk/kmlfilename.txt  does not contain valid KML markup.There could be other issues, but this one is the first that jumps out.

Comment: No, that's just the location of the file, which then gets passed to the Google Maps API, so the Google Maps API can locate it and load it.

Comment: But then the value of var kmlCoords becomes a path to a file, when it should be a lat/lon value. It's all a bit mixed up. By the way, please note that extended discussions are not accepted in comments here. The site is suggesting that it should be moved to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14083/discussion-between-cherryduck-and-marcelo)

Answer (score -1):

the error might be caused by not following this format:

***src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"***

see, after "YOUR_API_KEY" there shouldn't be "sensor=false". 
try it. hope it works.

Comment: Please don't sabotage your answer.